# How to remove the Action Bar from a Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-appcompat

I am trying to remove the action bar from an activity.

I have done following but its still keeping the Action bar on my Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ .. }
```

**Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TM.TMActivity"
    style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use **`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`** its working for me

**e.g**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Comment: and do i need to add this style on `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: still getting the Action bar

Comment: @Kirmani88 Just go to res->values->styles. Put the code given above there. It should definitely work. If you are still getting it then in your activity's onCreate function call getSupportActionBar().hide();  
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In styles.xml in values folder,

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Still Action bar is there

Comment: try removing the style attribute in `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 3):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

In your activity You can disable.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the correct style has mentioned in the manifest file.

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And in your style file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Check your build.gradle(app) also for dependency.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:x.x.x'
```

There is no need to mention style in Coordinator/Frame layout. Remove the following line from all the layout and try.

```
style="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```